# Linux freezing randomly

Tags: arch-linux, windows, freeze, out-of-memory, resources

My Computer has been freezing **a lot** lately, and with no apparent reason.
It freezes even if my usage is 3% CPU and 9% RAM.

I was using Windows 8 until  I installed Ubuntu 14.04.

It was **really** slow, and after some researching, I adopted the idea that Ubuntu 14.04 wasn't really **that** stable, so I decided I'd download a less resource-heavy distro, so I installed Arch Linux (which is what I'm using to type this now) with GNOME. I'm not having any of the problems I used to have in Ubuntu, except for this mostly annoying freeze that happens to be absolutely random ..

My Fan is working correctly, so it's not temperature, and my drivers are up-to-date (they're the same ones I used on Windows, which I had no problem at all with).

Note that: The Whole OS just freezes, and when I was once able to Alt+F2 (to get to the run-a-command dialog) and managed to type in a command (I was struggling with the keyboard to type) and hit Enter, I got the message: No enough memory .. ? Which is pretty unexpected because I'm using a minimal system (arch linux) with only one application running ..

#### Edit: Here's my /etc/fstab file

```
# 
# /etc/fstab: static file system information
#
# <file system> <dir>   <type>  <options>   <dump>  <pass>
# /dev/sda3
UUID=2268132b-7cfa-4c55-b773-467c4f691e83   /           ext4        rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1

/dev/disk/by-uuid/2236F90308C55145 /mnt/2236F90308C55145 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,user 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/4FF142A03DACFA48 /mnt/4FF142A03DACFA48 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,user 0 0
```

#### lsblk outputs ..

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0      2:0    1     4K  0 disk 
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  69.9G  0 part /mnt/2236F90308C55145
├─sda2   8:2    0  59.2G  0 part /mnt/4FF142A03DACFA48
├─sda3   8:3    0  90.3G  0 part /
└─sda4   8:4    0  78.7G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: https://bbs.archlinux.org/ or #archlinux on Freenode is probably a better place to debug an issue like this

Comment: Can you run 'lsblk' and include it in the post?  I'll also tell you that while arch in a great distro (my preferred) it is not a beginner distro. Mint is a better starter distro.

Comment: @StevenWalton: Added that. I'm not really a linux beginner, I've used pear os (before it was discontinued) then ubuntu for about 6 months, then I returned to windows for .NET Development for 2 months, then used Ubuntu 14.04 for 2 months (a big struggle) and then I decided I'd move to an intermediate distro like arch. It's a pretty long history, but despite that I've acquired some useful linux knowledge, like: BASH, GNOME, KDE, Man Pages, zsh, linux filesystems, etc.

Comment: Just wanted to check, because you do need bash knowledge with arch.  Anyway, your partitioning concerns me.  First off, I don't see a swap at all, unless you have a 78.7G swap.  You'll have memory problems without swap.  Your root partition should really not be bigger than 25G, especially when staying minimal.  I'd also find a better naming scheme for your home folders (weird set up too).  If this solves it I'll write an answer so we can mark it as solved. If not, I'll continue to help, but we'll need more info.

Comment: @StevenWalton: So .. You say I should boot from a live cd, run gparted: resize my root partition to 40G (that's the least I can get, because I download and delete a lot) and create a 2G swap partition ?

Comment: Well if this is a recent install I'd just reformat the whole disk.  But if not, then yes.  That would be the quick way, but could delete stuff (so be careful).  But seriously, that root partition is huge. I usually make one that is 20G when my disk is 1T. If you're installing a lot to root then you're managing your profiles incorrectly.  Would you like a suggested partition scheme?

Comment: @StevenWalton: Thanks for your concern. Well, that's a recent install that happened to come after a whole disk format (by mistake, I then recovered my files using a boot disc program) so I suppose I'll take the second route. I don't install a lot, I have actually installed several libraries and languages for development. The reason I make it huge is because I like to download 70-min length videos from time to time which clearly take space ..

Comment: Well take those videos and put them in one of your home partitions.  If you want two home partitions then I suggest the following partition scheme.  100Mb for / boot, 20G for / (root partition), 4G for [SWAP] (use this guide http://goo.gl/yMf7Ez), and split the rest between your two homes (/home1, /home2). Or one just one home (suggested), so you can add accounts freely.  Let me know if this clears the problem for you.

Comment: @StevenWalton: That's good. But I'm not really a fan of partitioning, because I try to keep everything simple so I just make a partition for / as a whole (90G) and probably also a swap partition (2G because I have 4G RAM). Is there anything wrong with this scheme ?

Comment: Should have 4G swap.  And then you should be fine.

Comment: @StevenWalton: This actually solved it ! Unfortunately, I had 4 primary partitions there already so I moved one's contents into another's, deleted the first and resized the other to fit all the contents while sparing 4.3G for swap space, then I added its UUID to /etc/fstab and used `swapon -a` to use it and (up until now) everything seems to be working correctly ! Post your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @AmrAyman, posted answer.  Happy to hear that it worked out for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't have any swap space.  Operating systems require a swap space so that they are able to free up ram space and store it on the hard drive.

What you are going to need to do is reformat your hard drive.  Red Hat has a suggest swap size chart [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s2-diskpartrecommend-ppc.html#id4394007).  Load up the arch live cd and repartition and `swapon /dev/sdaX`.  If you need a reference see the [Arch Wiki Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/beginners%27_guide#Create_filesystems).

I'll suggest a partition like the following one.

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0    20G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda4   8:4    0   rest  0 part /home
```

This is just suggested, you can do everything in a single partition and not worry about much (but this is the basic format that most people use).  If you are keeping your root partition separate then remember to keep it around 20-25G.  This is a security thing, because users should be installing programs into their own folders.  You won't run out of space, I promise.  Pacman and yaourt will take care of this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some points which may help you a bit to diagnose the problem:

- Run `free` command to see memory usage
- Run `top` and then hit `M` to sort by memory usage or `P` to sort by CPU usage to see which program uses your resources
- Be sure that at `/etc/fstab` is a line to mount swap - you see swap usage after `free`
- look at `/var/log/messages` or in case you are using `systemd` run `journalctl` and search for any warnings/errors.